# How to upload a file with unknown name using cURL

Tags: linux, curl

I am trying to upload a .tgz file to Chart Museum, and I am following the documentation found [here](https://chartmuseum.com/docs/#uploading-a-chart-package) which states that I should use.

```sh
curl --data-binary "@mychart-0.1.0.tgz" http://localhost:8080/api/charts
```

Since I do not know the file name I was trying to pass in a dynamic file name like this:

```
find ./ -name "*.tgz" | curl -L --data-binary @- http://localhost:8080/api/charts
```

But that does not work either.

### Question

How can I find the file, then have curl upload that data-binary to this API.

Thanks in advance!

TLDR;
How do you push a dynamic file using cURL and --data-binary

Answer (score 0):

Could you run this in a bash script to achieve the similar result?

for i in `find ./ -name xx*`

> do
>   curl -L --data-binary $i 'http://localhost:8080/api/charts'
>   done;

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.